# While loop not executing passed the user input

Tags: python, random, while-loop

```
#imports a library to call on random integers
import random

user_choice = ''
random_num1 = 0
random_num2 = 0
random_num3 = 0


#keeps the loop going until ended by the user
while user_choice != "n":

user_choice = input(f'Welcome to the slot machine, would you like to play (y)?: ')
random_num1 = random_num1 + random.randint(0, 10)
random_num2 = random_num2 + random.randint(0, 10)
random_num3 = random_num3 + random.randint(0, 10)



#prints the random integers side by side
print(random_num1, random_num2, random_num3)

if random_num1 == random_num2 and random_num2 == random_num3:
  print('Jackpot!!')
elif random_num1 == random_num2:
  print('Matched 2!!')
elif random_num1 == random_num3:
  print('Matched 2!!')
elif random_num2 == random_num3:
print('Matched 2!!')
else:
print('Sorry you lost!')

user_choice = input(f'Play again (y)?: ')
```

I'm sure there is more than one issue going on here, however it won't go passed asking Welcome to the slot machine, would you like to play (y)?: for me to troubleshoot anything further, I've tried rearanging the different lines and formatting the random integers differently (at one point it was just infinitely printing 3 random integers) and I just can't find a similar problem. I'm pretty new to python and any help is appreciated.

Comment: working fine you just need to indent properly!!

Comment: Any Python IDE will point out the obivous: that you apparently copied and pasted this code from somewhere, without getting the indentation right. There's nothing here, once indentation is restored, the code works as expected (although it keeps summing the values, which is probably not intended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indent properly.

**Code:** [with proper indentation]

```
#imports a library to call on random integers
import random

user_choice = ''
random_num1 = 0
random_num2 = 0
random_num3 = 0


#keeps the loop going until ended by the user
while user_choice != "n":

    user_choice = input(f'Welcome to the slot machine, would you like to play (y)?: ')
    random_num1 = random_num1 + random.randint(0, 10)
    random_num2 = random_num2 + random.randint(0, 10)
    random_num3 = random_num3 + random.randint(0, 10)
    
    
    
    #prints the random integers side by side
    print(random_num1, random_num2, random_num3)
    
    if random_num1 == random_num2 and random_num2 == random_num3:
      print('Jackpot!!')
    elif random_num1 == random_num2:
      print('Matched 2!!')
    elif random_num1 == random_num3:
      print('Matched 2!!')
    elif random_num2 == random_num3:
      print('Matched 2!!')
    else:
      print('Sorry you lost!')
    
    user_choice = input(f'Play again (y)?: ')
```

**Output:**

```
Welcome to the slot machine, would you like to play (y)?: y
7 2 3
Sorry you lost!
Play again (y)?: y
Welcome to the slot machine, would you like to play (y)?: y
13 9 6
Sorry you lost!
Play again (y)?: y
Welcome to the slot machine, would you like to play (y)?: y
21 15 15
Matched 2!!
Play again (y)?: y
Welcome to the slot machine, would you like to play (y)?: y
24 20 17
Sorry you lost!
Play again (y)?: n
#while loop exit
```

Comment: I don't think correcting indentation warrants an answer, the question should be closed as OP apparently just copied and pasted the code from somewhere.

Comment: yes the question should be closed.. as he is just a newbie just giving this answer so that he know how to indent properly. @Grismar

Comment: I copy and pasted it from my notepad, I was testing it in colab, which is where I saw it wasn't running. indenting it properly did allow my code to run.